# const variables in header files have "defined but not used" warnings

Tags: c++, constants, warnings, header-files

I have defined multiple `const` variables in my header file. When I compile, however, some of them have this `defined but not used` warning, while some do not.

For instance, the following does not have this warning:

```
const double var1 = 20;
```

But the `var3` does:

```
const double var3 = func(var2);
```

where `func()` is an inline function defined at the beginning of the same header file, as

```
inline double func(double x) {
  double d = var5 * pow(x, var4);
  return (d + var6);
}
```

Here `var2` to `var6` except `var3` are all `const` variables defined like `var1` (no warnings) in the same header file like:

```
const double var2 = 100;
const double var4 = 50;
const double var5 = 2;
const double var6 = 10;
```

I am curious why there is a warning at `var3`.

Also, the warning occurs at `var8` only:

```
extern const int var6;
const int var7 = var6;
const int var8 = var7;
```

I can disable the warning, or, make all variables as `extern const` and define them in a source file, which may also exclude the warnings, I guess. But I am just wondering what are the reasons that some are warned but some are not. Thanks.

Comment: Please review [MCVE]

Comment: You must see the linkage starting from your `main` method. If the `main` does not use them, they not gonna be evaluated. So, what contains your `main` ?

Comment: "Disable the warnings" is pointless.  If your code does not use a definition, you can delete the line with no impact.  This warning is something to be 'tolerated' for a short time ... reminding the author (you) that you planned to use it somewhere.  When your code is 'working', and you still have an Aunt Ethel in the basment (i.e. an unused definition), remove the symbol.